# Removing restriction on characters in cart in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, cart

I am using the cart library in Codeigniter. I am using this :

```
$product = array(
  'id'      => $product_id,
  'qty'     => $product_qty,
  'price'   => $product_price,
  'name'    => $product_name,
  'attr_id' => $product_attr_id,
  'short_desc'=> $product_short_desc,
  'options' => array('size_id' => $product_size_id)
);
$this->cart->insert($product);
```

Some products are not being added because it has disallowed characters in name. I want to remove that restriction. I commented this code in `my_project/system/libraries`:

```
if ( ! preg_match("/^[".$this->product_name_rules."]+$/i", $items['name'])) {
    log_message('error', 'An invalid name was submitted as the product name: '.$items['name'].' The name can only contain alpha-numeric characters, dashes, underscores, colons, and spaces');
    return FALSE;
}
```

But its still not adding to cart. Can someone help me in this ?

Comment: Show one example of such string

Comment: when name is Victoria's Shirt or short_desc is Girl's  then this happens. I think the character ' creates the problem here.

Comment: when I debugged its entering the regex check, but when i commented it nothing is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using this function before adding anything to the cart.. product  name or id or anything..

```
function quote_smart($string)
{
    $string = html_entity_decode($string);
    $string = strip_tags($string);
    $string = trim($string);
    $string = htmlentities($string);
    $string = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ',$string); // Removing more than one space/Tab.

    // Quote if not integer
    if (!is_numeric($string)) 
    {
        $string = mysql_real_escape_string($string);
    }

    return $string;
}
```

I just removed it and it worked!!
Thanks evryone for your answers.

Answer (score 4):

Just Try:

In system/libraries/Cart.php You can find :

```
  <?php
class CI_Cart {

    // These are the regular expression rules that we use to validate the product ID and product name
    var $product_id_rules   = '\.a-z0-9_-'; // alpha-numeric, dashes, underscores, or periods
    var $product_name_rules = '\.\:\-_ a-z0-9'; // alpha-numeric, dashes, underscores, colons or periods
 ?>
```

Don't make changes in above file but Create a new file called My_Cart.php in application/libraries, and enter the following code:

```
<?php 
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class MY_Cart extends CI_Cart
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->product_name_rules = '\d\D'; //This will override `$product_name_rules` rule from system/libraries/Cart.php
    }
}
?>
```

This solution involves overriding the Cart class and clearing the name restrictions.

Comment: I created the file in the path specified by you. But its still not working.

Comment: @noob Try modifying `var $product_name_rules = '\.\:\-_ a-z0-9';` to `var $product_name_rules = '\.\:\'\-_ a-z0-9';` in system/libraries/Cart.php

Comment: @noob You can accept my answer If my solution helped you to resolve the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```
$this->cart->product_name_rules = '[:print:]';
$this->cart->insert(array());
```